# R plumber Installation SSH key Error on creating droplet in Digital Ocean

Tags: r, windows, ssh, rstudio, digital-ocean

I am trying to deploy R plumber API on digital ocean (DO).

I am using windows 10 and following [these steps](https://www.rplumber.io/docs/hosting.html) to create droplets from RStudio. For SSH keys, I am using PuTTY key generator, followed step mentioned [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/droplets/how-to/add-ssh-keys/create-with-putty/) and saved private key in c:/user/myname/.ssh folder and uploaded public key as copy and paste into the Add SSH section as describe  [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/droplets/how-to/add-ssh-keys/to-account/).

The problem I am facing is an “Error please install ssh“ when I am creating a droplet from RStudio.

```
mydrop <- plumber::do_provision()
```

I can see the droplet is created on DO control panel, however, when I am copying and pasting the IP address in the browser window to see the results I get “problem loading page” /  ” Unable to connect “.

If I am trying to install any other R package, I get the same error,

Error Image :

[image]

or if I deploy using this code

```
plumber::do_deploy_api()
```

I get the same.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you already have figured this out. if not, please try installing the `ssh` package.

```
install.packages("ssh")
```